# How can I open a folder on server by clicking on a link

Tags: html, jsp

I have some docs which are located on a shared folder on the server. I need to open up this folder to show these docs by clicking on a link. I tried using `<a href="...">` but that didn't work. I don't want to point to any specific file on the folder.  If it's the case then it works, but what I want to do is to just open this shared folder by clicking on a link specifying the path.

The technologies which I can use are html, jsp, javascript, jquery.

Please advise how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java API to get the files of the folder and display each file as a link on the page.

```
 File directory = new File("path of shared directory");
 File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Display the files on the page as link, so this will be same as you do currently but it will get all the files in that directory.

Comment: Hi, I am getting null when try to display the files. This is the code which i tried <%
  File directory = new File("//abc/admin/ReleaseNotes/FY13");
          File[] files = directory.listFiles();
         out.print(files);
           %>